# Java and objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following structure:

[image]

I have class `A` with an `ArrayList`. This lists elements that are objects from class `B`. Objects in Class B's `ArrayList` are if type class `C`.

I want to add a method to class `A`, so I could add an element (of specific index in `ArrayList A`) to class `B`'s `ArrayList`.

Something like this :

```
class A -> ArrayList A -> index 2-> B.add(some_element);
```

Is this directly possible, or must I first get an object from `A`'s array-list, and make changes and add it back?

Comment: It's not very clear, you should give code of the three classes. Something like A.get(2).geB().add("I'm new"); ?

Comment: can you share some code to make some things more clear?

Comment: What you suggest is the nice solution. The new method in `A` will call a method in `B` to add to `B`’s list. So you will need to write new methods in both classes. It’s worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have three classes A, B and C you could simply do it like this:

```
class A {
    ArrayList<B> arrayListB = new ArrayList<>();
}

class B {
    ArrayList<C> arrayListC = new ArrayList<>();
}

class C {
    String cName;
}
//for example setting attribute cName, in first element of arrayListC, in the first element of array listB in obj a (of type class A) 
 A a = new A();
 a.arrayList.get(1).arrayList.get(1).cName="sth";
```

BUT I strongly discourage you to do so, cause it violates the Law of Dimiter [link here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-law-of-demeter-java-examples) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393155/how-to-obey-law-of-demeter)

Comment: I agree with the discouragement. Why are you showing the poor solution and not the good one? PS “Law of Demeter” is also known as “don’t talk to strangers”.